# Add to seperate databases Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How do I access different class databases and add/commit to them?

For instance, I have these two database models within my Flask app.

```
class classroom(db.Model):
    cName = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    cUsername = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    cWhere = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    cLimit = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)


class check(db.Model):
    vUsername = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    vWhere = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    vLimit = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

And I want to add data to them separately `db.session.add(new_classroom)`, how do I specifically tell the program to only send that data to the classroom database, and if I want to send data specifically to the check database, I can do that too.

I have tried setting a name for the table, however this does not change anything...

Comment: When you say database, I think you are meaning table or just model. " I have these two database models within my Flask app"
The model is mapped to one table, So table model is more appropriate. IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand you but calling

```
db.session.add(new_classroom)
```

and don't forget to commit it to the db to save the object right after:

```
db.session.commit()
```

this will add a new classroom object to the DB without involving the check table.

Regarding your last comment about setting a name for the table, I am not sure I understand what you mean, please explain and give the code sample and I will try to help you out